# C# iterator with string key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I wish to write a class similar to the dictionary class where I can add the text value of an object and return the object.

I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this in C# 3.5 without having a dictionary object inside my class (without using the dictionary class).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want the Dictionary class? After all it does exactly what you need?

Comment: I think what I need is a special class that contain certain fields bundled with the dictionary. so i can place multiple of those in a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean a string indexer?

```cs
class Foo
{
    public object this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            // Get the value.
        }
        set
        {
            // Set the value.
        }
    }
}
```